# How can I reuse the key value of the search parameter in the replace parameter in str_replace()?

Tags: php, str-replace

What would be the syntax to reuse the key value of the search parameter in the replace parameter, for example

```
$key = array($value1, $value2, …);
echo str_replace($key, "<span class='key'>$key</span>", $content);
```

The above will return an Array rather than a single array item.

Comment: The replace parameter can also be an array: [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#63783)

Comment: Yes, but I want to use each value of $key, which are strings.

Comment: Are you wanting to loop through the `$key` array and do a `str_replace` on each element, but do so 'in place' (not using a for loop)?

Comment: My understanding of str_replace is that it would search for any of an array of values and replace them; so I imagined that, given a value for $key, I could replace that value with the second parameter. I could use a loop to do something else, if I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use preg_replace_callback. Str replace doesn't accept arguments in the replacement string.

```
$key = array($value1, $value2, …);
$regex = addslashes(implode('|', $key));
$content = preg_replace_callback(
  "/$regex/",
  function ($matches) {
    return '<span class="key">'.$matches[0].'</span>';
  },
  $content
);
```

bitWorking has a better answer though if you can make each value in the array it's own regular expression.

Comment: This works, I set $content = preg_replace_callback( … ) then echo $content.

Comment: I updated my answer to store the returned string to $content like in your original example.

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$key = array('/a/', '/b/');
echo preg_replace($key, '<span class="key">$0</span>', 'a b');
```